# onnxruntime: cannot import name 'get_all_providers'

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

Trying to import onnxruntime in a Jupiter notebook with python 3.6.3 on macOS.
I get the following error on import:

```
import onnxruntime


ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-df664b79ebd4> in <module>
----> 1 import onnxruntime
      2 

~/.virtualenvs/3.6nlp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxruntime/__init__.py in <module>
     11 __author__ = "Microsoft"
     12 
---> 13 from onnxruntime.capi._pybind_state import get_all_providers, get_available_providers, get_device, set_seed, \
     14     RunOptions, SessionOptions, set_default_logger_severity, NodeArg, ModelMetadata, GraphOptimizationLevel, \
     15     ExecutionMode, OrtDevice, SessionIOBinding

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_providers'
```

I have looked at similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607359/issues-with-onnxruntime-on-ubuntu-16-04?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C85.6234)
but haven't found the answer that works for me.

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: How did you install onnxruntime?

Comment: via pip install: pip install onnx onnxruntime

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the issue is with libomp not being installed. If you run into this problem you can solve it by running

```
brew install libomp
```

Hope this helps if you get stuck like me